# Invalidate browser cache for resources in HTML file

Tags: html, caching, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

Suppose I have an HTML page, say `http://mywebsite.com/index.html` which includes a remote JS file `http://mywebsite.com/source.js`.

My HTML file is never cached as expiry is set as an old date. But `source.js` is cached in browser as expected.

But whenever I change content of `source.js`, I want to force all clients to invalidate browser cached `source.js` and fetch a fresh one. From next time, it should again be served from browser cache.

I know one approach could be adding a version number to filename or adding a query parameter to it in HTML file. But there are multiple such resources on my page and I don't want to do this for all.

So, I want to explore if there's a way to set some marker in HTML file or some HTML response header to invalidate all cached resources for the website.

Answer (score 0):

There's many different ways to handle caching and lots of headers you can set. There is a great article on [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).

I would suggest you take a peek at `Etag` and `Last-Modified` headers, the Etag is essetially a fingerprint so when its downloaded your browser keeps track of the Etag, then when the file is changed the web server generates a new Etag and associates it with the file... so when your browser checks it it gets the new Etag and downloads the new copy of the file, but if the etag is the same it doesn't bother and uses the cached copy.

Comment: thanks @John. But should we set "Etag" header for all files/resources or setting it for HTML page will work for all?

Comment: You want an Etag on any static content that should be cacheable.